# Call template function from within a template class

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, cuda

GCC will not compile following code snippet (which in fact is correct behavior of GCC as it is conform to the standard C++ as I have learned already. VC++ however will compile.)

```
template<class T>
void CUDAMemory1D2DTextureAllocator<T>::allocateMemoryOnDevice()
{
    m_pChannelDesc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<T>();
    ...
}
```

As i already found out by searching is, that one needs to tell the compiler that `cudaCreateChannelDesc` is a template method. Otherwise it will try to
parse `<` as a smaller than operator...

The following snippet shows that in an easy example:

```
template< typename G >
struct Test
{
    template< typename T > T f() const;
};

template< typename G, typename T >
void g()
{
    Test< G > t;

    t.f< T >();           // ERROR: gcc won't compile that
    t.template f< T >();  // OK: now gcc knows that f is a template method an treads the following angle brackets  not as operators but as template brackets...
}
```

So far so good. Now my question is, how to do that in the above case, where the method I call is `cudaCreateChannelDesc` which does not belong to any class or namespace?
Any advice or suggestion how to solve this situation are very welcome.

Thanks

Comment: You only need `template` when it's a template member function, not the creation of a temporary. Show us your code, the definitions of all the identifiers you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call it directly like: `cudaCreateChannelDesc<T>()` if it doesn't belong to any class or namespace. Isn't it working like that?

Comment: Thanks. Yes you are correct. I can call the function like that (as I tried in the first place) The problem was, that the template class I wrote was derived from a Serializer Class where an specialized instance of the template class was created. I have to recheck the hole code involved here to understand what happened. But somehow this brought up the compiler error in gcc stating "expected primary-expression before '>'" which leaded me to the thought that he had issues resolving that cudaCreateChannelDesc was a template itself.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that `cudaCreateChannel1Desc` is not a global or namespace function, because that should work, unless you forgot an include or a namespace resolution. And you do say it is a "method", i.e. a member function.

So, if it is a method of class `CUDAMemory1D2DTextureAllocator`, then you should use `this->template cudaCreateChannel1Desc<T>()` to call that method (which I have deduced is a method of a templated base class of `CUDAMemory1D2DTextureAllocator`. Below is a compact illustration of what works and what doesn't in different situations (at least on gcc):

```
template <class G>
struct Base {

  template< class T > 
  T h() const {
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
  };
};

template< class G >
struct Test : public Base<G>
{
    template< class T > 
    T f() const {
      std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    };

    void callF() const {
      f<G>();                //works!
      this->f<G>();          //works!
      h<G>();                //ERROR!
      this->h<G>();          //ERROR!
      this->template h<G>(); //works!
    };
};
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the error. In fact i did not mean 'method' but 'function'.

Answer (score 1):

Is the `cudaCreateChannelDesc` function declared in some namespace that you have in scope?  It appears that you might be having a problem with two-phase name lookup, which requires that some entities (like functions) referred to in templates need to be visible even before the template is instantiated.  If you write a non-templated function in the same place as you definition of `allocateMemoryOnDevice` and call `cudaCreateChannelDesc` inside it, does the code compile?  If not, you might be missing a `#include` or a namespace qualification on `cudaCreateChannelDesc`.

Comment: Dan Paradox is right. It is working as he states, as the function did not belong to any class or namespace. It was some other error that mislead me. See my comment on Dan Paradox answer for details.